# Can I get charts with higher quality?

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart

I've created a new Chart, looks like this in asp.net (using mvc):

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Number of errors")
        .AddSeries(            
            xValue: @ViewBag.Chart.xVal,
            yValues: @ViewBag.Chart.yVal)
        .Write();
}
```

And this gives me this image:

[image]

You might not see it, but on my supersmooth lcd screens the images has areas with dither

**SOLVED**:

```
@{
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddTitle("Number of errors")
            .AddSeries(            
                xValue: @ViewBag.Chart.xVal,
                yValues: @ViewBag.Chart.yVal)
            .Write("png");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is the Chart from the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly, the default format is Jpeg. Try passing `"png"` as the `format` parameter to the `Write` method.